# How many ways can we send X letter if we can use Y messenger and each messenger gets at least one of the letters

Tags: combinatorics

> We have 6 letters to distribute amongst 3 messengers. Assuming that each messenger gets at least one of the letters, how many ways are there to distribute the letters?

My attempt at solution is to consider a simpler case, such as how many ways to send 3 letters if there are 2 messengers and each messenger gets at least one of the letters.  In this case the answer is 6 because I have listed them all, but i have no idea to solve a question like this without listing them.

Comment: What does "each letter can be given to any of them but all three messenger have to go and send it." mean?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, can you improve it?  Suppose you only had one letter (but still had three messengers subject to whatever the rules are).  What's the answer in that case?

Comment: Sorry my mistake,what i mean is how many way to send a letter if all the messenger have to go and send it.But of course im asking for a case if the letter is always more than the messenger

Comment: All you did was reprint the same words as before.  Why on earth would I need three messengers to deliver a letter that only one of them had?

Comment: I suspect he means that *every messenger has to work at least a little*, which is to say: distinguishable urns, distinguishable balls, and a restriction of at least one ball per urn.

Comment: Im asking in case that the letter is more than the messenger

Comment: @DanUznanski  that's quite a reach.  Maybe the OP can confirm it?  If so...then if there's only one letter, you'd say the answer was $0$?

Comment: Dan Uznanski+ that is what i mean sorry for not being clear

Comment: It makes sense for the answer he gave for 3 messages and 2 messengers: you can have $1|23$, $2|13$, $3|12$, $12|3$, $13|2$, $23|1$, but not $123|$ or $|123$.

Comment: @DanUznanski  And it looks like the OP has confirmed that reading.  Want to write up an Inclusion/Exclusion argument? (or whatever method...)

Comment: We have $3$ options for each one of the $6$ letters, so the answer is $3^6$. The general answer is $Y^X$.

Comment: @barak manos But that include only one messenger sending the letter,what i want is every messenger has to work at least a little

Comment: I suggest editing the post, it really isn't clear as written.  If I understand correctly, all you mean is "We have $6$ letters to distribute amongst $3$ messengers.  Assuming that each messenger gets at least one of the letters, how many ways are there to distribute the letters?"

Comment: OK, got it, will answer shortly (to long for a comment.

Comment: i have edited the post,sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 3):

There are, of course, $3^6 = 729$ possible messenger assignments if we don't care whether one's sitting at the office bored all day.

But quite a few of these assignments have some of the messengers bored.

There are $$\binom{3}{1}1^6 = 3$$ ways to have a single messenger of the three carry all six messages.

For two messengers, we can use a similar calculation, but we must *exclude* certain duplicates: if I distribute the messages all to Alice and Bob, there's a way to distribute them all to just Alice, and similarly I can distribute them all to just Alice if I say I'm distributing to both Alice and Charlie, so I have to exclude that possibility *once* so we don't count it *twice*.

$$\binom{3}{2}2^6-\binom{3}{1}1^6 = 189$$

For three messengers this works the same way: we must exclude the situations in which two or fewer people get all the messages.  Fortunately we just calculated that!

$$\binom{3}{3}3^6-\left(\binom{3}{2}2^6-\binom{3}{1}1^6\right) = \binom{3}{3}3^6-\binom{3}{2}2^6+\binom{3}{1}1^6=540$$

In the second version, you'll note that the sign on the one-working-messenger term is positive.  Another way of thinking about this is that now we've excluded "alice alone" twice, so it appears -1 times in the final count, so we have to *include* it again.  This alternation of including and excluding things is called the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Using it, we can generate a general form for the answers to this type of problem:

If we have $m$ messengers and $\ell$ letters, then the number of ways we can distribute the letters to the messengers without any of the messengers getting no letters and becoming bored is $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}\binom{m}{k}k^\ell$$

It looks like this value is $m!\times S(n,m)$, where $S$ is the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  OEIS has this sequence as [A019538](http://oeis.org/A019538).

Answer (score 2):

We apply the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  There are $3^6$ ways to distribute the letters if we ignore the constraint. We seek to exclude the cases in which one or more messengers gets no letters.  First we exclude all those distributions in which one specified messenger gets no letters.  If, say, we exclude Messenger $A$ then there are $2^6$ ways to distribute.  As there are three messengers, we first subtract off $3\times 2^6$.  But now we've removed too much...to be precise, we have twice excluded the cases in which one messenger gets all the letters.  There are $3$ such cases.  Thus the answer is $$3^6-3\times 2^6+3=540$$

Sanity Check:  If we did your special case of $3$ letters and $2$ messengers by this method, we'd get $$2^3-2=6$$  as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that each messenger sends at least one letter, then you need to use *inclusion/exclusion* principle. For example, given $6$ letters and $3$ messengers:

- Include the number of ways in which at most $\color\red3$ messengers work: $\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\color\red3^6=729$
- Exclude the number of ways in which at most $\color\red2$ messengers work: $\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\color\red2^6=192$
- Include the number of ways in which at most $\color\red1$ messengers work: $\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot\color\red1^6=3$

Hence the answer is $729-192+3=540$.

---

For the general case of $M$ messengers and $L$ letters (assuming $M \geq L$):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{M-1}(-1)^n\cdot\binom{M}{M-n}\cdot(M-n)^L$$